# Build Failed: No such module 'KIF'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, kif

I've been having a sporadic issue when attempting to reference KIF in my Swift project.

My project stopped compiling after I did a "clean", and has been giving me the error: `No such module 'KIF'`

Here is my cocoapods file entry for KIF:

```
target 'MyProjectTests', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0', :configurations => ['Debug','QA']
end
```

(This is the recommended cocoapods config from [KIF's readme](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF#installation-with-cocoapods).)

I can get it to compile again by changing the cocoapods entry from the above to:

```
pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0'
```

But the project crashes when attempting to run:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /Users/albertbori/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/29008343-5A97-47FB-B0E6-66D18A331BDA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C0E16F80-9A08-4228-96F7-8A24F08AB066/MyProject.app/Frameworks/KIF.framework/KIF
  Reason: image not found
```

Then, if I switch it back to the original config, and do a `pod install`, testing with KIF works again...

How can I reference KIF correctly to ensure stable building and development with that framework?

Comment: Looking at the pod spec for KIF, this seems because they override `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` to a custom value. Which I don't think includes XCTest.

Comment: Yea, I assume it's because they anticipate that you'll use the `target 'MyProjectTests', :exclusive => true do` condition to keep it out of a deployment. I just can't get it to compile with that condition in place.

Answer (score 0):

After posting [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/swift/issues/29) on CocoaPods issue tracker, [kylef](https://github.com/kylef) helped me realize that I was inadvertently double-linking the pods.

Here is [his pull request](https://github.com/albertbori/catch22/pull/1) to resolve the issue on an example project I made.

In summary, the Podfile should look something like this, if you want to link both the root project and a test project, but conditionally add an extra pod to the test target:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'Locksmith'

target 'catch22Tests' do
  pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0'
end
```

In this case, you **DO NOT** want to use: `link_with 'catch22', 'catch22Tests'` or it will link `catch22Tests` twice.